# How to sort dataset by greater value of 2 columns in a row?

Tags: sql, delphi, ms-access

I have a database of rooms made up of `Room_Widths` and `Room_lengths`. I want to be able to order the dataset using a `TADOQuery` in Delphi, so that the room with the longest side, whether it's the width or the length will be first in a dataset. I need this so that I can perform a bin packing algorithm on it later.

I hope, there is something that will look fairly similar to this:

```
ADORoomQuery.SQL.Add('ORDER BY GREATEST(Room_Width, Room_Length)');
```

For example if I have 3 rooms (9 x 9m), (10 x 2m) and (5 x 12m):

```
Room_Widths    Room_Lengths
-------------  -------------
9              9
10             2
5              12
```

Then it would return the following dataset:

```
Room_Widths    Room_Lengths
-------------  -------------
5              12
10             2
9              9
```

I'm using MS Access database.

Comment: What database are you using ? Could you [`edit your question`](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/15175716/edit) and include this information ? Thanks, and welcome to StackOverflow!

Comment: Oh ye thanks i new there was gonna be something i forgot if you need any more information just ask :)

Comment: I've expanded your example, so to make it little bit cleaner...

Comment: wow thank you so much thats made it look a lot clearer!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

maybe something like this:

```
  select 
     room_widths, 
     room_lengths, 
     iif(room_widths>room_lengths, room_widths, room_lengths) as longest
  from 
     yourtable
  where 
     <your select criteria>
  order by 
     3 desc
```

Comment: what does the 'order by 3' part do? im still learning some of the sql and database stuff so sorry i this is an obvious question

Comment: order by 3rd column, but you could also do "order by longest", you added that you use Access, I'm sure they have an if, but you'd have to check to see how they implement it.

Comment: @user582118 . . . I think the correct function in Access is `iif` not `if`.

Comment: @user582118 . . . In that case, you should have used the ANSI standard `case`.  There is no `if` in most databases.  Unfortunately, Access doesn't support case.

Comment: so this wont work using my combination of delphi and MS Access?

Comment: The `CASE` expression is not supported by Access, `IIF` is. The code from this post should work for you. Here's a [`fiddle for MSSQL`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/1d068/5/0). [+1]

Comment: oh thats too cool! Ill give this a try and post back in a minute or so

Comment: hmm i get an error saying that the parameter 'Longest' has no default value, is the Longest part of it something that access knows about?

Comment: @JabbaWook make sure you have all the commas in the iif statement, iif ( condition, value_if_true, value_if_false ) - The value_if_false is the default value

Answer (score 1):

You could try normalising your data first. For example:

```
select
  RoomID
, 'W' as Dimension
, Room_Widths as DimensionValue
from yourtable
union all
select
  RoomID
, 'L' as Dimension
, Room_Lengths as DimensionValue
from yourtable
order by RoomID
```

Suppose you save the above query as NormalisedRooms. This should give you something like:

```
RoomID  Dimension  DimensionValue
------  ---------  --------------
     1          W               9
     1          L               9
     2          W              10
     2          L               2
   ...        ...             ...
```

Now you can do:

```
select
  RoomID
, max(DimensionValue) as LongestSide
from NormalisedRooms
group by RoomID
order by 2 desc
```

This should give you:

```
RoomID  LongestSide
------  -----------
     3           12
     2           10
     1            9
```

Comment: Oh ye this was going to be my backup method i was just testing to see if there was a way to do it directly with SQL, Thanks for this though if i do fall back on this method this will come in handy.

Answer (score 1):

ok thank you for the suggestions. I ended up using @Tlama @GordanLinof @user582118 suggestions to return the dataset in an already ordered state.

the delphi syntax and sql i used was:

```
with ADOLayoutQuery do
  begin
    SQL.Clear;
    SQL.Add('SELECT Room_Width,Room_Length,IIF(Room_Width > Room_Length, Room_Width, Room_Length) AS Longest');
    SQL.Add('FROM RoomDetails');
    SQL.Add('WHERE OrderNumber = ' + inttostr(OrderNum));
    SQL.Add('ORDER BY IIF(Room_Width > Room_Length, Room_Width, Room_Length) DESC, (Room_Width + Room_Length) DESC');
    Open;
  end;
```

you guys might be able to condense this slightly but this has worked for me. Again thank you for you help and i look forward to asking my next question